# After including page I am facing ajax error (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I am working on notification system. So I am following this blog (http://www.phptutorials.club/ajax-notification-in-php-with-example/).
Please see the code.

It's working fine and it's giving me a notification, but the problem is if I include the page in another index.php page, then it's giving me (error (Not Found).

I renamed the index.php as notification.php and I am including it on my website index.php page. So after including it's giving me an error but without including it's working fine.

Please suggest I know PHP but don't know about ajax and jquery,js.

Please see my code below.

notification.php

```
   <style>
    #notification_count {
        padding: 0px 3px 3px 7px;
        background: #cc0000;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-left: 77px;
        border-radius: 9px;
        -moz-border-radius: 9px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-top: -1px;
        font-size: 10px;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function addmsg(type, msg) {

        $('#notification_count').html(msg);

    }

    function waitForMsg() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "select.php",

            async: true,
            cache: false,
            timeout: 50000,

            success: function(data) {
                addmsg("new", data);
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg,
                    1000
                );
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
                setTimeout(
                    waitForMsg,
                    15000);
            }
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {

        waitForMsg();

    });
</script>




<span id="notification_count"></span>
<a href="#" id="notificationLink" onclick="return getNotification()">Notifications</a>
<div id="HTMLnoti" style="textalign:center"></div>



<script>
</script>
```

select.php

```
    <?php include "../../includes/db.php" ?>

<?php
       $sql = "SELECT * from comments where comment_status = 'unapproved'";
       global $connection; 

 $select_comments= mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die('Could not look up user information; ' . mysqli_error($connection));                

       $count = mysqli_num_rows($select_comments);
       echo $count;
        mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

So after including the notification.php file in index.php.it's giving me an error.
But without including this file. it's working fine.

```
<!--  Notification panel-->
                   <?php include "../includes/notification.php" ?>
```

Comment: Add your code also

Comment: please post your sample code so that we can help you

Comment: code has been added. Please see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check if your include path is correct. Try:

```
<?php include "../../includes/notification.php" ?>
```

Additionally, check the path to `select.php` in your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "select.php",
    ...
```

Second, you should think about splitting notification.php into three parts:

- put CSS into main .css file
- JavaScript code should be in notification.js
- HTML code you can leave in notification.php

Then include notification.php in the index.php after you have included .css and .js files.

Comment: As a PHP developer, I'd like to see the php logic split from the html as well.

Comment: I agree. Haven't noticed php code in notification.php though.